# Create a query to return number of produced products based on date in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a query to get the total number of produced products for each day in Microsoft Access.
Here are the few rows of my table as a sample:the table's name is **Orders**

```
      ordernumber    number of products    Date  
           100              2              11-May-16  
           101              1              11-May-16  
           121              2              24-May-16   
           122              3              24-May-16  
           131              1              25-May-16  
           105              3              11-May-16  
           127              1              24-May-16 
           135              2              25-May-16
```

The desired output is :

```
     TotalNoProducts        Date  
           6              11-May-16  
           6              24-May-16  
           3              25-May-16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the more basic aggregate queries:

```sql
SELECT SUM([number of products]) As TotalNoProducts, CDate(Int([Date])) As TheDate
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CDate(Int([Date]))
```

Note that you can also build this query through the query builder, which is usually easier for beginners than using SQL

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just understood that, unfortunately, the question I asked is not explaining the problem properly. Since the date column, also consists of time, this query doesn't return my desired output. I mean date column is like following:   11/05/2016 10.31.58, 11/05/2016 12.19.54, 24/05/2016 16.14.30,24/05/2016 16.14.22, etc . And I need to know the total number of products in each day despite the time of production during the day. I am a beginner to access and SQL , so I guess this might be a very basic problem. Thanks again

Comment: See the current edit, and make sure you provide all relevant information next time.

Comment: Thanks Erik. it worked. I'll take your advice for next time :D